# My OpenGL program shows the top perspective, not front, why?

Tags: opengl, blender

I made a small OpenGL program that should become a game someday. I made a model in Blender and exported it as a STL file. But when I draw the model in my program (by reading the STL file), it was shown from another perspective. (I believe it was from top.) I thought it would show up in the front view. Like the front view in Blender. This is the code how I draw the triangles.

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glVertex3f(x1, y1, z1);
glVertex3f(x2, y2, z2);
glVertex3f(x3, y3, z3);
glEnd();
```

I played with the values and found out that this will show it from front.

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glVertex3f(x1, z1, -y1);
glVertex3f(x2, z2, -y2);
glVertex3f(x3, z3, -y3);
glEnd();
```

So my question is how to do it the RIGHT way, not just that it works. It doesn't look right to switch y and z coordinates. Is there a OpenGL function to change the perspective or something like that. Why is it from top?

Thanks

Comment: Blender uses the [right-hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) coordinate rule with Z pointing up, which is common in cad programs but not so much in other 3d apps. Most exporters give an option to translate the up and forward axis.

Answer (score 1):

Rotate the model-view matrix by 90 deg over X axis before rendering the object.

The reason that You see Your object from the "top" is because Z axis of a model in Blender is up/down or top/bottom while in OpenGL it is back/front. [This](https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems) is a tutorial showing what I mean.

Comment: Most blender exporters also have an option to swap the y and z axis when you export your model.

Comment: "because Z axis of a model in Blender is up/down or top/bottom while in OpenGL it is back/front" Thank you, that was the answer. I rotated it as you said and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You look at the geometry from the top, because on the viewport the X axis from the left to the right and the Y axis is from the bottom to the top. It follow, that in [right handed coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Orientation_and_handedness) the Z-axis points out of the viewport (opposite line of sight).

[image: view coordinates]

Of course this could be handled by a 90° roation around the X-asis:

```
glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity()
glRotatef( -90.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
```

But, to define the view to your scene you can use the function [`gluLookAt`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml), which does the necessary transformations.

The parameters of this function are:

- the position from where you look at the scene
- the point in the scene were you look at
- the upwards direction

This parameters have to be setup in world space. See the following example with a position of (0, -1, 0), a target of (0, 0, 0) and an up vector of (0, 0, 1):

```
glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt( 0.0, -1.0, 0.0,    0.0, 0.0, 0.0,    0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
```